# ffmpeg is adding around 2 seconds to the end of each video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm not a developer or anything like that, so I just copied scripts from different places until I made it work, so please bear with me here...

I'm using this script and all my videos get 2 extra seconds at the end:

```
/ffmpeg -loop 1 -i PathToMyImage -i PathToMyAudio -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest PathToMyTheOutputMP4File
```

For example, if the audio is 2min long, the final video ends up being 2:02

Comment: So you mean the final video has the length of the audio + 2 seconds?

Comment: Hi, @RicardoBohner. Yes, that's what's happening. If the audio is 2min long, the final video will be 2:02, for example. I'm not sure if it's EXACTLY 2 seconds, but around 2-3 seconds, yes.

Comment: If you know that the audio has exactly 2min you could use -t 120

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The videos are always different lengths. I will check the answer below (mentioning "-max_interleave_delta 100M") and see if that fixes it. If not, I will definitely use your suggestion. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the post
[My ffmpeg output always add extra 30s of silence at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800185/my-ffmpeg-output-always-add-extra-30s-of-silence-at-the-end).

The explanation in the accepted answer is as follows :

> Containers (AVI, MP4, MKV) usually store multiple streams in an
> interleaved fashion i.e. a few seconds of video, then a few seconds of
> audio, and so on. So ffmpeg buffers data from all streams, when
> writing.
>
> `-shortest` acts at a relatively high-level and is triggered when the
> first of the streams has finished. However, buffered data from other
> streams will still be written to file. `-fflags shortest` acts at a
> lower level and stops the buffered data from being written when used
> with a sufficiently high max_interleave_delta.

You are using `-shortest`, but are not specifying `max_interleave_delta`.

The answer suggests using `-max_interleave_delta 100M`.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc I will definitely check that out. I'm completely new to ffmpeg and the whole shell scripting world, so I hope I will be able to understand what's wrong. Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: I just tried it and it works, @harrymc! :) Now I have a question: why the `100M`? is this related to something specific? Is this something I need to change depending on the length of the video or something else? Thank you!

Comment: All the parameters are described in the [ffmpeg(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg), but may change slightly between ffmpeg versions and implementations. Unfortunately I can't say which parameters are best for your case.

Comment: Thanks again. I saved that link for reference along with the help documentation provided by Terminal. For now it's working, so I will leave it at that. Really appreciate your time and help @harrymc 